# ytdl-core no stream data

Tags: node.js, youtube, discord, discord.js

I am making a NodeJS Music bot for discord, and I suddenly encountered a problem. The bot properly joins the channel, lights up (indicating it is speaking), but then there's no audio. After trying to find the root cause of the problem, I believe it to be a problem with the `ytdl()` function from the `ytdl-core` module.

```
const stream = await ytdl(song.url, {
    filter: 'audioonly',
    type: 'opus',
    highWaterMark: waterMark
  });
```

Looking at the result of stream, I found this:

```
PassThrough {
  _readableState: ReadableState {
    objectMode: false,
    highWaterMark: 524288,
    buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },
    length: 0,
    ...
```

Which meant that I am not getting any buffer/stream data. It is indeed playing, but because there's nothing-- there's only silence to be heard.

I tried using `pipe()` and it worked just fine, but I can't play it as it is through my Music Bot.

Answer (score 0):

ytdl function is like synchronous function.

`"ytdl-core": "^4.10.1"`

`const stream = await ytdl(song.url);` pause code execution until `ytdl` finished downloading stream.

```
console.log("YTDL Start");
const stream = await ytdl(song.url, {
    filter: 'audioonly',
    type: 'opus',
    highWaterMark: waterMark
});
console.log("Is it done?");

stream.on('close', () => {
  console.log('Read stream closed');
});

stream.on('finish', () => {
  console.log('Read stream Finished');
});
```